# online or offline topographic-type model creator program

Tags: modeling

The most difficult part of this is the terminology used to search, in my opinion. In the past year, I discovered a (probably online) resource which allows one to draw shapes in three-space. That's obviously a vague reference.

I've added in topographic, as that is the closest approximation to the type of shapes that are created, but it's not a geographic-type topographic sort of thing. If one looks at a topographic map, there are curves for each elevation. There are topo resources which allow one to, for example, laser cut each elevation and assemble the geography as a model. This is not what I seek, but the individual layers could have been created in the software I desire to locate.

[image: layer dinosaur]

The image above represents the result of the program I wish to find. One would select a plane, draw a series of curves representing the spine, then add additional planes for each of the ribs and tail segments.

It was a fairly impressive resource and I believe it was online. I should have bookmarked the site, either for the online aspect or if it was a downloaded program, to download it later, but my bookmarks are empty and my installed program list equally so.

If one could provide a set of valid search terms, that would be helpful. Of course, hitting the exact web site is the best result.

Answer (score 1):

The answer arrived to my alleged mind in a burst of inspiration. I had posted a link to a laser-cutter forum and was able to locate my original post. The program is called [flatfab](http://flatfab.com/) which certainly makes sense considering the features and results.

[image: dino flatfab image]

These images have been taken from the source web site, which provides a free download for the program (not online as first thought) as well.

[image: screen capture of software]

Windows, Mac and Linux supported!